# Firebase auth persistence with getReactNativePersistence(ReactNativeAsyncStorage) with loading screen

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I'm making an app with React-Native, and making my own save/load user's auth with Expo SecureStore and a loading screen.

At first, everything works, but when I must add rules for end test mode, I get a problem with `auth` persistence. So I adopt, as the terminal recommended, the method with `getReactNativePersistence()` like so:

```js
const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
    persistence: getReactNativePersistence(ReactNativeAsyncStorage),
});
```

But how can I implement the loading screen?

Answer (score 0):

In App.js scrivi un useEffect che gestisca tutto questo.
Ad esempio:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const initUser = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        const userData = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('user')
        setUser(userData)
        setIsLoading(false)
    }

    initUser()
}, [])
```

Comment: Ciao Mauro, grazie per la risposta, ma quello era ciò che avevo fatto da solo precedentemente, ma firebase mi richiede di utilizzare la loro funzione initializeAuth con la persistence nelle props come dicevo: const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
    persistence: getReactNativePersistence(ReactNativeAsyncStorage),
}); è qui che ho difficoltà a capire come poter implementare il tutto.

Comment: Ciao Mauro, grazie ancora per la disponibilità, sto comunque intraprendendo la strada per costruirmi il backend da solo in node.js... Se non sono troppo intromettente vorrei chiederti un consiglio, io ho studiato alle superiori , quindi circa 20 anni fa programmazione, poi sono entrato nel mondo tessile aprendo un' azienda durata più di 10 anni, e della quale ho impostato tutta la struttura informatica. Ma oggi non vi è più la possibilità di produrre in Italia, l' azienda non è chiusa ma quasi. Vorrei entrare nel mondo della programmazione, mia grande passione fin da quando ero ragazzo.

Comment: Che consigli puoi darmi ,come posso entrare in questo mondo non avendo esperienze pregresse? Penso di essere portato per questo lavoro e da solo ho studiato javascript, react , react native e node.js, sviluppando questa appa per farmi curriculum... Come posso emergere? hai dei consigli? Grazie